Configure Spring Security 6 with Oauth2
I'm migrating my Springboot 2.4.3 Application to Springboot 3.2.3. Since WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated I'm trying to configure SecurityFilterChain as below. But When I make an API call, all Calls fail with 403Forbidden. Please help me to resolve this issue.
TIA
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterRequestChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
            auth -> auth.requestMatchers(properties.getWhiteListEndPoints().toArray(new String[0]))
                .permitAll().requestMatchers("/**").authenticated());
    http.exceptionHandling(
        httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer -> httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer.accessDeniedHandler(
            restAccessDeniedHandler));
    http.oauth2Client(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
  }

Here is my property file
security:
  oauth2:
    resourceserver:
      jwt:
        user-info-uri: https://xxxxx/openam/oauth2/tokeninfo
    client:
      registration:
        custom:
          client-id: ccccc
          client-secret: xxxxx
          scope: ocean
          grant-type: client_credentials
          access-token-uri: https://xxxx/openam/oauth2/access_token?realm=/xyz

LOG:
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Detected SessionLocaleResolver
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Detected FixedThemeResolver
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@72943338
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@162b0f27
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Completed initialization in 8 ms
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@7c764a04, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2a8a173b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3b74fc81, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1075b601, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@195b823a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@650aed6b, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@24c7f8eb, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@43f17f5, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@604a7303, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4cfa25d1, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter@36a33153, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2ef70cb4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6c87de1c, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@51e92ae3]] (1/1)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Securing GET /v1/logfile
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking CorsFilter (5/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking LogoutFilter (6/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (7/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter (11/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking SessionManagementFilter (12/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (13/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking AuthorizationFilter (14/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@5a763779]
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@5a763779] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@6eb73b1a
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter.java:183) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:181) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@7c764a04, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2a8a173b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3b74fc81, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1075b601, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@195b823a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@650aed6b, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@24c7f8eb, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@43f17f5, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@604a7303, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4cfa25d1, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter@36a33153, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2ef70cb4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6c87de1c, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@51e92ae3]] (1/1)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Securing GET /error
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking CorsFilter (5/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking LogoutFilter (6/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (7/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter (11/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking SessionManagementFilter (12/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (13/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Invoking AuthorizationFilter (14/14)
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@25c61e7d]]
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@25c61e7d]] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@6eb73b1a
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-05-05 10:48:15 - Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at 


Please state the reason for not enabling debug logs and reading the reason for your 403 before asking here

identity provider configuration is missing, your client does not know where to get identity https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#oauth2login-custom-provider-properties
spring:
 security:
  oauth2:
   client:
    registration:
      okta:
        client-id: okta-client-id
        client-secret: okta-client-secret
    provider:
      okta: 
        authorization-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/authorize
        token-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/token
        user-info-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
        user-name-attribute: sub
        jwk-set-uri: https://your-subdomain.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/keys


Hi @Nikita,
We use openAm-based Authorization and the above properties aren't working for me.
